# Join two dictionary list on ID

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have two dictionary list

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list1 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list2 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
List<Dictionary<string, string>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

list1=    [ { ID="3", Date="12/28/2013", Target="1",...},
            { ID="4", Date="12/30/2013", Target="33",... }]
list2=[ { ID="3", ASO="100", Below="50"},
           { ID="4", ASO="40", Below="33" }]
```

Now I want the result would be

```
result= [ { ID="3", Date="12/28/2013", Target="1", ASO="100", Below="50",...},
           { ID="4", Date="12/30/2013", Target="33", ASO="40", Below="33",...  }]
```

Result is formed on `list1 id = list2 id`.
Above code is just like idea
here is my complete code

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list2 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
List<Dictionary<string, string>> listresult = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
var summary = (from a in _context.tblReportProfessions
    where a.tblBRReport.ID==4 || a.tblBRReport.ID==5||a.tblBRReport.ID==3
    select new
    {
        ID = a.tblBRReport.ID,
        DateOf = a.tblBRReport.ReportDate.ToShortDateString(),
        Target = a.tblBRReport.frnchiseTarget,
        Name=a.tblCampaignProfession.tblAllProfession.ProfessionName,
        Qty=a.NoOfConsumer
    })
    .ToList();
var summary2 = (from a in _context.tblReportAges
    where a.tblBRReport.ID == 4 || a.tblBRReport.ID == 5 || a.tblBRReport.ID == 3
    select new
    {
        ID = a.tblBRReport.ID,
        Name = a.tblCampaignAge.StartAge + "-" + a.tblCampaignAge.EndAge,
        Qty = a.NoOfConsumer
    })
    .ToList();

int id = 0;
Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var ex in summary) 
{
    if (id == ex.ID)
    {
        result[ex.Name.ToString()] = ex.Qty == null ? "" : ex.Qty.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (id != 0)
        list.Add(result);
        id = ex.ID;
        result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        result["ID"] = ex.ID.ToString();
        result["Date"] = ex.DateOf;
        result["Target"] = ex.Target.ToString();
        result[ex.Name.ToString()] = ex.Qty == null ? "" : ex.Qty.ToString();
    }
}
list.Add(result);

int id2 = 0;
Dictionary<string, string> result2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var ex in summary2)
{
    if (id2 == ex.ID)
    {
        result2[ex.Name.ToString()] = ex.Qty == null ? "" : ex.Qty.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (id2 != 0)
        list2.Add(result2);
        id2 = ex.ID;
        result2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        result2["ID"] = ex.ID.ToString();
        result2[ex.Name.ToString()] = ex.Qty == null ? "" : ex.Qty.ToString();
    }
}
list2.Add(result2);
```

Now i want `listresult=list.Join(list2)` how to do it.id is common key

` How to merge the two dictionary list? Anyone helps me is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:list Data (Json Format From Firebug)

```
    0
    Object { ID="3", Date="12/28/2013", Target="1", more...}

Business
    ""

Date
    "12/28/2013"

Driver
    "33"

Farmer
    "33"

ID
    "3"

Labor
    ""

Others
    ""

Puller
    "33"

Service
    "33"

Student
    ""

Target
    "1"

Unemployed
    ""

1
    Object { ID="4", Date="12/30/2013", Target="33", more...}

Business
    "33"

Date
    "12/30/2013"

Driver
    ""

Farmer
    ""

ID
    "4"

Labor
    ""

Others
    ""

Puller
    ""

Service
    ""

Student
    "33"

Target
    "33"

Unemployed
    "33"
```

list2 data

```
0


Object { ID="3", 18-25="33", 26-30="33", more...}

18-25
    "33"

26-30
    "33"

31-35
    "33"

ASO-35
    "33"

ID
    "3"

1
    Object { ID="4", 18-25="33", 26-30="33", more...}

18-25
    "33"

26-30
    "33"

31-35
    "33"

ASO-35
    "33"

ID
    "4"
```

I want to join based on ID of list and list2 and send result to browser.

Comment: You appear to only have lists of your custom type - not really dictionaries. It would help if you'd give a short but complete program demonstrating your data. If you don't *currently* have a custom type involved, I'd suggest you create one if possible.

Comment: There's a missing custom type here.

Comment: I try to make it simple.Anyway i give the complete souce

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, you're projecting into anonymous types, which then need to be grouped. See my response.

Comment: Key is generated dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i want the following

```
 Dictionary<string, string> listResultitem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach(var dic in list)
        {
            foreach (var dic2 in list2)
            {
                if (dic["ID"] == dic2["ID"])
                {
                    listResultitem = dic.Concat(dic2.Where(kvp => !dic.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
                    listresult.Add(listResultitem);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

provided data is not `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`. But with anonymous types you can try the following:

```
var list1 = new []
{
    new {ID = "3", Date = "12/28/2013", Target = "1"},
    new {ID = "4", Date = "12/30/2013", Target = "33"}
};

var list2 = new[]
{
    new {ID = "3", ASO = "100", Below = "50"},
    new {ID = "4", ASO = "40", Below = "33"}
};

var result = list1
    .Join(
        list2,
        arg1 => arg1.ID, 
        arg2 => arg2.ID,
        (arg1, arg2) => new 
        {
            arg1.ID, 
            arg1.Date, 
            arg1.Target, 
            arg2.ASO, 
            arg2.Below
        })
.ToArray();
```

but it really seems that you need some custom types involved here.

Comment: I have edit my question.if u can help me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @decoder removed my edit. Can you describe what data you what to get in the end? Why do you need lists of dictionaries? Try to use `Join` like mine on your `summary` and `summary2`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for List's containing dictionaries:

***Setup of example***

```
var list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> {
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ID", "3" }, { "Date", "12/28/2013" }, { "Target",  "1" }},
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ID", "4" }, { "Date", "12/30/2013" }, { "Target", "1" }}
};

var list2 = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> {
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ID", "3" }, { "ASO", "100" }, { "Below", "50" } },
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ID", "4" }, { "ASO", "40" }, { "Below",  "33" } }
};
```

***This is what is interesting for you***

```
var result = from first in list
            join second in list2
            on first["ID"] equals second["ID"]
            select new { ID = first["ID"], Date = first["Date"], Target = first["Target"], ASO = second["ASO"], Below = second["Below"]};
```

And it gives you this (exactly the result you wanted)

`ID Date        Target ASO Below`

`3  12/28/2013  1      100 50`

`4  12/30/2013  1      40  33`

Comment: I have edit my question.if u can help me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Column is dynamic.it is not fixed like this

Comment: What do you mean? Each dictionary in each collections has key "ID". You said you wanted to join dictionaries based on that key.

Comment: Here is two list of dictionary.i want one list.every element of list one has key ID.and Every element of list2 have key ID.I want to join two dictionary on based of ID key

Comment: I don't understand. You say I have two lists when you want one. Then you say you have 'list one' and 'list2' that each contain elements with key ID. In your example you have to lists of dictionaries (list, list2).

Comment: Business
    ""

Date
    "12/28/2013"

Driver
    "33"

Farmer
    "33"

ID
    "3"

Labor
    ""

Others
    ""

Puller
    "33"

Service
    "33"

Student
    ""

Target
    "1"

Unemployed
    "" this is one element of list

Comment: 18-25
    "33"

26-30
    "33"

31-35
    "33"

ASO-35
    "33"

ID
    "3" this is one element of list2

Comment: this two element should be one element in resulting list

Comment: And that's exactly what my code is doing - only that it doesn't select all keys from each dictionary. But I guess you know how to do it? - just change the last line (select).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44147/discussion-between-peri-and-decoder)

Comment: is there any way to get the all keys of a dictionary?

Comment: I answered you in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

Attached is a solution with custom type:

ForEach loops can obviosly be converted to LINQ, but is not to increase the readabilty.

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string ASO { get; set; }
    public string Below { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObjectMerger
{
    public List<CustomObject> Merge()
    {
        List<CustomObject> list1 = new List<CustomObject>();
        List<CustomObject> list2 = new List<CustomObject>();
        List<CustomObject> result = new List<CustomObject>();

        list1.Add(new CustomObject { ID = "3", Date = "12/28/2013", Target = "1" });
        list1.Add(new CustomObject { ID = "4", Date = "12/30/2013", Target = "33" });

        list2.Add(new CustomObject { ID = "3", ASO = "100", Below = "50" });
        list2.Add(new CustomObject { ID = "4", ASO = "40", Below = "33" });

        foreach (CustomObject customObject1 in list1)
        {
            foreach (CustomObject customObject2 in list2)
            {
                if (customObject1.ID == customObject2.ID)
                {
                    result.Add(new CustomObject { ID = customObject1.ID, ASO = customObject2.ASO, Below = customObject2.Below, Target = customObject1.Target, Date = customObject1.Date });
                }
            }
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edit my question.if u can help me is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a list of a dictionary? That does complicate things, but it's still possible to do what you want. I have a feeling you should be working with two `List<T>`'s, though.

Your example is incomplete - it's missing your custom types, so it's hard to determine exactly what you're trying to do. However, if you're working with custom types, you often need a 3rd composite type to project your results into - I have just used the second type in this example.

However, I think what you're trying to do is group and project. I've just bashed this together to show you, assuming there really is a custom type in your original code, and you want to group on the ID field (again, an assumption). I've broken it down into sections so it's a bit more readable:

```
        public void PerformTest() {
            var list1 = new List<Dictionary<string, MyCustomType>>();
            var list2 = new List<Dictionary<string, MyCustomType2>>();

            list1 = new List<Dictionary<string, MyCustomType>> {
                new Dictionary<string, MyCustomType> {
                    {
                        "key1",
                        new MyCustomType {
                            ID = "3",
                            Date = "12/28/2013",
                            Target = "1"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "key2",
                        new MyCustomType {
                            ID = "4",
                            Date = "12/30/2013",
                            Target = "33"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            list2 = new List<Dictionary<string, MyCustomType2>> {
                new Dictionary<string, MyCustomType2> {
                    {
                        "key3",
                        new MyCustomType2 {
                            ID = "3",
                            Date = "12/28/2013",
                            Target = "1",
                            ASO = "100",
                            Below = "50"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "key4",
                        new MyCustomType2 {
                            ID = "4",
                            Date = "12/28/2013",
                            Target = "1",
                            ASO = "100",
                            Below = "50"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var innerList1 = list1.SelectMany(x => x.Values);
            var innerList2 = list2.SelectMany(x => x.Values);

            var list3 = innerList1
                .Join(innerList2, x => x.ID, x => x.ID, (x, y) => new MyCustomType2 {
                    ASO = y.ASO,
                    Below = y.Below,
                    Date = x.Date,
                    ID = x.ID,
                    Target = x.Target
                });
        }

        public class MyCustomType {
            public string ID = "3";
            public string Date = "12/28/2013";
            public string Target = "1";
        }

        public class MyCustomType2 {
            public string ID = "3";
            public string Date = "12/28/2013";
            public string Target = "1";
            public string ASO = "100";
            public string Below = "50";
        }
```